# How can I define a different style for edges and nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given this image (a simple edge between two nodes):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
  \node (a1) at (44bp,8bp) [draw,trapezium] {$A$};
  \node (d1) at (44bp,82bp) [draw,trapezium, shape border rotate=180] {$B$};
  \draw [->] (d1) ..controls (44bp,62.836bp) and (44bp,41.478bp)  .. node {$edge$} (a1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I defined:

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[drop shadow, fill=white, draw]
```

What happends is that also the node on the edge gets rendered in a box and with shadow. I want the edge label to be just the text without loosing the `every node` rule.

Thus my question is: Is there a way I can specify specific rendering for nodes in edges while keeping all other nodes with shadow?

I must note that my tikz picture is generated, thus I only have control over the `every` styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using an `edge` in the TikZ sense in your drawing, it's just a normal path with a node ( TikZ `edge` is created by using `\path (A) edge (B)`). As such, no `every ...` style that's specific to the "edge" node is installed, and you can't hook into it.

Since you say your image is generated (how?), you might have to approach this a bit differently. Instead of making `every node` have a drop shadow, you can apply the shadow just to `every trapezium node` in this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every trapezium node/.style={
        drop shadow, fill=white, draw
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
  \node (a1) at (44bp,8bp) [draw,trapezium] {$A$};
  \node (d1) at (44bp,82bp) [draw,trapezium, shape border rotate=180] {$B$};
  \draw [->] (d1) ..controls (44bp,62.836bp) and (44bp,41.478bp)  .. node {$edge$} (a1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you might want to actually make the style `every trapezium node` instead of `every node` in the code. Like you say in the text `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Jake. I figured that is the way for doing this. I was hoping for an answer in the direction of being able to be able to be more specific and do something like `every draw node`. That way I can also enable automatic shadows on all other types of nodes, except nodes on "edges".
The tikz is generated by [dot2texi] (http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) btw.
Why do you include `every path`? Is this to show there are no TikZ edges?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong code.